# Optimally convert (small) boolean expressions into NOR form by hand

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, optimization, nand

Is there a way to easily convert a boolean expression with only few variables into a NOR form?

Let's take the half-adder as an example:

```
a b | sum
---------
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0
```

The sum of products is:
$$sum = \overline{a} b + a \overline{b}$$

If I convert that to a form which only involves NAND gates with 2 inputs, I get:

$$sum = \overline{a}b + a\overline{b} = \overline{\overline{\overline{a}b + a\overline{b}}} = \overline{\overline{\overline{a}b + a\overline{b}} + 0} = \overline{\overline{\overline{a + \overline{b + 0}} + \overline{\overline{a+0} + b}} + 0}$$

I count 6 NOR gates.

However, if I first write the boolean expression as a product of sums:
$$sum = (a + b) \cdot (\overline{a} + \overline{b}) = \overline{\overline{a+b} + \overline{\overline{a} + \overline{b}}} = \overline{\overline{a+b} + \overline{\overline{a + 0} + \overline{b + 0}}}$$

**Now, there are only 5 NOR gates.**

As I guess this is a heavy optimization problem (as suggested by [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-20505-7_36), I'd like to ask whether there is a way to 'optimize' it in small boolean expressions (e.g. < 3 variables).

Furthermore, I'd be interested in an answer regarding the same question with NANDs as well as the same problem appears there, too.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xor+gate&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiziqLg38XLAhWCchQKHZw2C2oQsAQIRA&biw=1293&bih=902

Comment: @Andyaka The goal is to convert the expression into a NOR form, so that it only consists of NOR gates with two inputs.

Comment: You can evaluate it using Wolfram Alpha with the input: NOR ((not a) and b) or (a and (not b))

Comment: Yes, so what didn't you see on the linked page (hint 1st picture)?

Comment: @Andyaka Do you mean [Wikipedia's XOR gate built from NOR gates](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/XOR_from_NOR.svg/320px-XOR_from_NOR.svg.png)? Well, I am searching for a general algorithm/tips for small functions.

Comment: I think your question is being masked by your words. Try and be specific.

Answer (score 1):

I question the real value of your question, since noone ever has only simple NOR gates to work with in practice. There are algorithms for finding near-optimal minimised solutions to less trivial expressions. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer

Brute force is the best approach for a small problem, I fear.